# Can different functions of a random variable be independent?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable. $f$ and $g$ are two non-trivial (e.g. non-constant) measurable functions defined on the range of $X$. Can $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ be independent? Thanks!

Comment: Any constraints on the probability space on which $X$ is defined?  For a uniformly distributed $X$ on a finite space with a composite number of elements this is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure they can be independent, but they can certainly be uncorrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ and $g$ can be independent if they are simple functions that attain finitely many values.  For example: take these functions on $[0,4]$

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac 12 & \lfloor x \rfloor \text{ is even}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\\
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac12 & \lfloor x/2 \rfloor \text{ is even}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

We have $$P(g(x)=C|f(x)=D)=P(g(x) = C)$$ 
and 
$$P(f(x)=C|g(x)=D)=P(f(x) = C)$$